# Batch File: works under cmd-Windows , NOT under MS-DOS

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, cmd, dos

I made these codes to backup files :

```
set p=C:\Users\
for /f %%a in ('dir C:\Users\ /b') do (
if not "%%a"=="Public", (
set fileDest=C:\Backup-%%a_%date:~7,2%.%date:~4,2%.%date:~10,4%
If Not Exist "%fileDest%" mkdir "%fileDest%"
set "fullPath=%p%%%a%"
xcopy "%fullPath%" %fileDest% /e /h /y /k
rem call blah.bat
)
)
```

When I test it under cmd of Windows 7 , it works great!!

When I try it under MS-DOS(VirtualBOX) it does not

It gives me these errors :

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid it is *normal*. What is your version of MS/DOS ?

Comment: MS-DOS didn't support spaces or long filenames until the last versions, so it didn't support double-quotes either. What version of DOS are you using in VirtualBox?

Comment: not sure, but I think, MS-DOS does not support any parameters with `for`. You can check with `for /?`

Comment: @Stephan yeah , "for" works!

Comment: Yes FOR works under MS-DOS, but I don't think FOR /F works. MS-DOS uses COMMAND.COM. I believe that FOR /F is one of many command extensions that is not available until introduction of CMD.EXE.

Comment: @dbenham any suggestion to let everything in my code work ?

Comment: If I can trust my (poor) memory, `SET /P` was not supported by MS-DOS 6.22 either...